# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:2.8.1

Tags: java, maven, mailmerge, docx4j

I am currently using docx4j version 2.7.1 but I need docx4j version 2.8.1 now.After I change the dependency in pom.xml for docx4j to 2.8.1, I get the error Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:2.8.1. How do I solve this?

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>massMail</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>massMail Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mapping commons collection jac in repo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Library to Read and Write Excel File -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Library to Read and Write .Xlsx file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>massMail</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- defining compiler for all java with 1.6 -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your pom worked on my machine. Check your settings.xml for proper remote repositories configuration.

Comment: @yevgeniymordovkin: how do i setup remote repositories configuration?

Comment: @Sujal have you changed anything in your `settings.xml` file , or is it the default one that comes bundled with the maven installation ?

Comment: @SaifAsif: its default. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Are you behind any firewall or proxy ? The entry for the docx4j seems fine to me. Try to run a `mvn clean install`

Comment: @SaifAsif: Yes I do have a firewall but don't think thats an issue. I've already done mvn clean and install. If it was an issue with firewall wouldn't it have caused problem while downloading other dependencies?